# html5 canvas caching tiles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making an MMO game in **HTML5 Canvas**. 
It's **isometric** and it has **tiles and walls**.

So I need to optimise the game for *slow computers/mobile devices*. 
For that I want to cache my tiles and walls:

Once they are drawn, they are static/not animated

so I don't need to redraw them each time.

I also don't want to use two (or more) `<canvas>` objects so I want to use the same `<canvas>` element that I'm using to draw with `requestAnimationFrame` my game items/entities.

I've alerdy tried to draw the tiles and the walls to an offscreen canvas with the same width/height as the visible canvas and then draw it each time on the visible canvas,

but the visible canvas uses the resolution of the page so it's pretty the same CPU usage with or without cache on high resolutions (like my current screen: *1920x1080*)

How should I do this properly so I can reduce CPU usage and use memory instead ? Is it impossible without using two canvases?

Comment: Because of the problem of depth occlusion the 2D canvas does not provide a good solution for isometric tile based games. You are forced to re-render the tiles and game sprites each frame. For isometric games you need to use webGL to render and then you can use the z-buffer for occlusion

Comment: @Blindman67 could you please provide me a demo of WebGL with dynamic images without the need to redraw all the canvas if you don't mind so I can see this in action?

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the static elements as an image after you draw the map for the first time and then call the image. It will be faster if you have a lot of elements involved into drawing the map.

If nothing overdraws these static elements during the gameplay they never have to be drawn again. Keep that in mind

EDIT: Alternatively you can draw smaller object and scale them ([refrence](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp))

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(5,5,25,15);
ctx.scale(2,2);
ctx.strokeRect(5,5,25,15);
```

The second rectangle is twice as high and wide.

Comment: Alerdy did that but instead of an `new Image()` object I was using the offscreen canvas like this: `ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)`
But there's still the problem about the canvas size

Comment: @JeePing Try the scale method to draw on the canvas. If any of the images draw are blurred try adding 'ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;'